# What is the power rating on this engine?

Tags: engine, vw

[image]

Took this photo from the engine of an industrial vacuum. The power rating says 58 kw, but the device can't possibly generate that much power. What is the proper way of reading these?

Comment: Why do you think it can't generate that much power?

Comment: Its because the engine is small.

Comment: How small? Would help to know more about it – type of fuel, number of cylinders, etc. The ID plate is a bit hard to read, but it looks like it might be an AFD engine which, as best I can tell after a quick search is a 1.9L diesel. It could generate that much power.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read it as 58 KW at 3,100 RPM – that's about 78 HP.

The engine code is a bit hard to read, it looks to me to be either an AFD or AFO, doing a bit of searching I found [Club VeeDub's list of engine codes](http://www.clubvw.org.au/vwengines). They show the AFD code was used for a 1.9 liter turbocharged diesel industrial engine rated at 60 KW (80 HP, the list says 90, but the math doesn't work out, I assume it's a typo). There is no entry for the AFO code.

I then searched on AFD and found [Specifications for Volkswagen Industrial Engine (AFD)](http://www.haywood-sullivan.com/vanagon/TDI/tdi_specs_en.pdf) which has output curves in it. The curve shows a power output of pretty close to 58 KW at 3,100 RPM. According to the specs there are two ECU codings available as stock, this engine appears to be coding 02.

I also found a technical brief, [1,9 ltr-TDI-Industrial Engine](http://www.haywood-sullivan.com/vanagon/TDI/tdi-technik-eng.pdf), which appears to be for the same engine, although it doesn't explicitly mention any engine code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to know if this can be used as a generator. I don't know anything about engines, but I've seen generators that output ~40kw and they are hugh. This engine is a part of an industrial sucker, so can I use it as an electric backup generator.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) the engine is turbocharged, you can get a lot of power out of a small package that way; 2) the engine is producing 58 KW at *3,100* RPM a 60 HZ generator will often be wound to run at 1,800 RPM, at 1,800 this engine will only produce about 38 KW and you'd probably not want to be asking it to do that (both for the sake of the engine and because the system isn't 100% efficient).

Comment: You might find this thread, [New to TDI : Thinking about Diesel Generator](http://forums.tdiclub.com/showthread.php?t=136193) from TDIClub interesting they are talking about using that exact engine. Also, if you pursue the engine make sure you get the ECU and intercooler and you might want to ask about the cooling system as well.

Comment: @dlu: Why not? At 1800RPM, the engine has max torque and so highest fuel efficiency. And for the sake of the engine, 1800 is better than >3000.

Comment: @sweber: agreed about 1,800, that would be a nice place to run it, much nicer than 3,600 (assuming 60 HZ). This engine is "coding 02" and will produce 40 KW at 1,800 and output would be pretty stable since that is max torque. Guess I'm just not so comfortable rating the engine at 100% continuous, plus 40 KW out of the engine will not turn into 40 KW out of the generator. But I don't think I said that very clearly up above. If the engine is rated for 100% continuous load, well then I stand corrected on that part.